# Beautifulsoup iterate to get either <td>sometext</td> or url

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I Want to create a list that contains a key-value pair. With the `<thead>` items as the key. For the values I want to get the text for all `<th>`items except the `<th>` items where there is a `<a href='url'>`, then I want to get the url instead.

Currently I am only able to get the text from all items. But how do I do to get '/someurl' instead of Makulerad and Detaljer?

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped zero-margin-top">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Volymsenhet</th>
      <th>Pris</th>
      <th>Valuta</th>
      <th>Handelsplats</th>
      <th>url1</th>
      <th>url2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      
     <tr  class="iprinactive">
        <td>Antal</td>
        <td>5,40</td>
        <td>SEK</td>
        <td>NASDAQ STOCKHOLM AB</td>
        <td><a href="/someurl">Makulerad</a></td>
        <td>
          <a href="/someurl">Detaljer</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

My code:

```
raw_html = simple_get('https://example.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class":"table"})
head = [th.get_text() for th in table.find("tr").find_all("th")]

datasets = []
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    dataset = dict(zip(head,(td.get_text() for td in row.find_all("td"))))
    datasets.append(dataset)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, try `dataset = dict(zip(head, [td.get_text() if not td.a else td.a['href'] for td in row.find_all("td")]))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this:**

simply get the text data of `<td>` if it doesn't have an `<a>`. Otherwise get the `href` value.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
raw_html = '''<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped zero-margin-top">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Volymsenhet</th>
      <th>Pris</th>
      <th>Valuta</th>
      <th>Handelsplats</th>
      <th>url1</th>
      <th>url2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>          
     <tr class="iprinactive">
        <td>Antal</td>
        <td>5,40</td>
        <td>SEK</td>
        <td>NASDAQ STOCKHOLM AB</td>
        <td><a href="/someurl">Makulerad</a></td>
        <td>
          <a href="/someurl">Detaljer</a>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class":"table"})
head = [th.get_text() for th in table.find("tr").find_all("th")]

datasets = []
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    dataset = dict(zip(head, [td.get_text() if not td.a else td.a['href'] for td in row.find_all("td")]))
    datasets.append(dataset)
print(datasets)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[{'Volymsenhet': 'Antal', 'Pris': '5,40', 'Valuta': 'SEK', 'Handelsplats': 'NASDAQ STOCKHOLM AB', 'url1': '/someurl', 'url2': '/someurl'}]
```